# Jinja2 format is not working with Raspberry Pi

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am trying to make a basic website in Rasberry Pi using Flask.

I am getting an error to render a html.

I try to use Jinja format but somehow it doesn't work.

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}

<h2>{the_title}</h2>
<form method="POST" action="/search4">
<table>
<p>Use this form to submit a search request:</p>
<tr><td>Pharse:</td><td><input name="pharse" type="TEXT" width="60"</td></tr>
<tr><td>Letters:</td><td><input name="letters" type="TEXT" value="aeiou"</td></tr>
</table>
<p>when you are ready,click this button:</p>
<p><input value="DO it" type="SUBMIT"</p>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Basic template code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>{{the_title}}</title>
</head>
<body>

{ % block body % }

{ % end block %}

</body>
</html>
```

What output I am getting at the moment:-

[image: Output]

My python code is here:-

```py
from vsearch import search4letters
from flask import Flask,render_template

app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates')

@app.route('/')
def hello()-> str:
    return 'Hello world from Flask'

@app.route('/serach4')
def do_search() -> str:
    return str(search4letters('life! the universe,and everything','eiru!'))


@app.route('/entry/')
def entry_page():
    return render_template('entry.html',the_title = """\ Welcome 
    to search4letters on the web!""")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug= True)
```

Is there any problem with the basic html page?

So, why Jinja2 can't understand the format?
or am I doing some mistake?

Could you please help me in this regards.

Comment: please show your base.html and your python code where you call the template.

Comment: Hello, thank you...yes I put basic.html code and python code as well

Answer (score 0):

Do not put spaces between `{ }` and the `%` in your Jinja2 templates:

```
{ % block body % }

{ % end block %}
```

If there are spaces, it will get treated as regular HTML strings, instead of [Jinja2 templates](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/). Also, it should be `endblock` (one word) instead of `end block`.

It should be:

```
{% block body %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: @SubrataMitra Glad I could help. If my answer helped you, [feel free to upvote or mark the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).